# Sharepoint list item permissions for manager of creator

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, permissions, visual-studio

Im creating a SharePoint application where a user puts their tickets. The ticket will be restricted by permissions to only be accessible by the creator, assignee and group of users which are responsible to assigning tasks.

The company is big and therefore managers need to have access to tickets which are submited by their employees. I can write an event handler which adds all required permissions to a concrete list item. But there is a problem with the manager. The manager of the user can change in time, because of that I cannot make easy access rights to the user's manager.

I need something more than permissions on a list item. I need security layer or something simular.
Is there any possibility to implement permission for manager of creator?

**EDIT:**
As i read more and more. The settings permissions to concret list item is not good practice. So is there any other option how to implement security?

In worst case i will make custom page where i can implement SPGridView with custom SPQuery for user to see only relevant stuff. I will also put some security check in dispform and editform for better restriction. But is there some better option?

Answer (score 0):

This is a corner use case. I would suggest creating a timer service which will go through open tickets and double check permission on a regular basis.

Else you need to go through the hard way of creating Custom Page + Forms etc.